# Flex, which is the opposite of "none" in setSyle?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I'm working on a Flex Mobile Project and I don't know which is the opposite of `none`.
For example:

```
textArea.setStyle("borderVisible", "none");
```

Which word I have to put to replace `none` for have got visible border?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`borderVisible` is a Boolean type, so you can set its value like this:

- textArea.setStyle("borderVisible", true);
- textArea.setStyle("borderVisible", false);

I'm surprised to see the "none" value gets parsed at all. Then again, it's probably auto-cast to a Boolean.

Comment: Thank you @RIAstar.. It works.. "none" works, I don't know why, but there isn't warnings and errors, so thank again..